# Why MySQL completely reformat the VIEW query text?

Tags: mysql, sql-view

Using Firebird and SQL Server, when I create an VIEW the query text remain exactly as I wrote. No matter if I use SQLDBX, IbExpert, FlameRobin or SSMS, it extracts the same query text.

But when it comes to MySQL, it COMPLETELY changes the query text. And when I extract it to a script, the carefully indented query text converts in a one BIG line of text.

It's indifferent if using an ODBC application (SQLDBX) or MySQL WorkBench, it's absolutely annoying.

After said that:

1. There's some reasoning about why this works that way?
2. There's any workaround?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

1. Because mysql was designed this way. It interprets the code and transforms it into canonical form in order to run it under any sql mode setting and in this process all indendations are lost. I would not even expect an rdbms to store the command in a nicely formatted way. That is not its purpose.
2. Store the views', stored procedures', tables', etc nicely indented code in your version control system, where they belong.

Comment: It's a nice excuse for design incompetence, IMHO.

Comment: I do not think it is a design incompetence. You should not rely on any rdbms' functionality to return nicely formatted code.

Comment: If databases initially designed in mid '80s can do that, it's a shame MySQL can't do something that basic. There's no excuse.
They know how to do it, as it doesn't happens to routines.

Comment: For stored procedures mysql preserves the sql mode setting that was in force when the stored procedure was created and each time a stored procedure is run, the preserved sql mode setting is used, not the actual one. Therefore there is no need to convert the code to canonical form. For views this setting is not preserved, therefore the command is converted to the canonical form in order to run it under any sql mode setting. And again, I would not expect any rdbms to store commands in a nicely formatted way, no matter when they were designed. The development tools should do that.

Comment: So, if you have to do support through the default tools available through some kind of remote desktop, you have to do reformat it manually to an legible text?
That's an shameless excuse.

Comment: I even gave up on asking to preserve the original text. * correction above: to get an legible text?

Comment: I accepted since appear there's no other way. Since I start to work on that database, it's really a pain in the back.

Comment: I don't agree with you, the 90s are already over. I am happy if we have switched to MS-SQL-Server.

Comment: @MichaelMaier again, all code should be in your version control system in a nicely formatted and commented manner. If you have to go to the information schema to retrieve it, then you are already in a big trouble.

Comment: I also agree that this is a poor excuse. While I agree that views, and other SQL code should be managed be a version control system and treated as part of the regular code base. What's the point of presenting query text if it's unintelligible? What's the point of having the feature if it's only halfway useful?